# Is it safe to use an American power adapter in India and Australia?

Tags: power, ac-adapter

I'm going to India and Australia on a business trip in a couple of days and plan to carry only a tablet instead of my trustworthy laptop (which got dunked in the tub by my oldest - don't ask). The adapter states the following:

100-240V~0.65A, 50/60Hz Output 12V===2A

Will it be safe to use the adapter in these countries to charge my device, or do I have to buy new ones there? If the latter, what kind? What else should I take along with me? A surge protector?

Comment: If you do bring a surge protector, make sure that it supports up to 240v if you want to use it without a voltage converter.  Otherwise, only plug it in *downstream* of the converter.

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of it, the adapter will work as long as you have the "adapter"!

```
India   
230 V
50 Hz
```

[image: Type D Socket and Plug]

```
Australia   
230 V
50 Hz
```

[image: Type I Socket and Plug]

<sub>[source](http://users.telenet.be/worldstandards/electricity.htm)</sub>

Comment: Austria != Australia

Comment: @Shinrai, miss-typed the name... the info is correct

Comment: Wasn't sure and didn't have time to check so figured I'd just throw it out there :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this chart](http://users.telenet.be/worldstandards/electricity.htm#voltage), both of those countries use 220-240 Volts at 50 Hz.  Your adapter says that it does support those voltages and cycles.

However, you will need adapters for the *shape* of the plug so that your plug will fit in the socket.  Most electronics stores carry these fairly cheaply.